# How to say "I bought this book for 1200 yen." in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

I want to say,

> I bought this book for 1200 yen.

My attempt is as follows but I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

- 私はこの本を１２００円買いました。
- 私はこの本を１２００円で買いました。

Comment: So which do you think is correct?

Comment: Maybe the latter.

Comment: hehe... you're right :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter is correct. The former is grammatically wrong as it roughly translates to "I bought this book 1200 yen" (lacking 'for', as denoted by で).

Comment: I'd interpret the first almost as 'I bought 1200円 worth of this book'.